# Css transition not working on parent when showing child content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, children

```
<div id='element-with-transition'>
    <div class='child'>
       <div style='display:none'>Something here...</div>
       <div style='display:none'>Something here...</div>
       <div style='display:none'>Something here...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
#element-with-transition{
        -webkit-transition: height 3s;
        transition: height 3s;   
}
</style>
```

When I change `display:none` to `display:block` the content is shown but the transition is not fired. I already tried changing the transition from height to all, but nothing changes. Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Where is your `selector`?

Comment: You might want to add '.child{ ... }' to your style

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The question related asks about transitions of an element from display:none to display:block, this asks about the parent element's transition.

Answer (score 1):

You can not change `display:none;` to `display:block;` with transition. If you want to animate height then your have to use `height:0; overfloaw:hidden;` for initial state then set `height:100px;` (or any desired value) for final state.

Comment: So, transition will ony work if I set a different fixed height  to the element?

Comment: Yes It should work. Don't change disply.. keep it block always & try changing height.